# How an object stores the static value serialVersionID while serialization and verifies it later while deserialization?

Tags: java

When an object is serialized, it doesn't store the static and transient state of an object. Hence, how it verifies the static value of serialVersionUID while deserialization? As for verification while deserialization, an object and the class, both will have to store the serial version reference. 
However, the object doesn't store static and transient state values while serialization therefore how it can verify?

Comment: Your information is incomplete. It certainly does store the uid. That's an exception though.

Comment: What you really need is a basic tutorial on the serialization mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the object is serialized, first a descriptor of its *class* is serialized (once only), and that descriptor contains the `serialVersionUID`. It isn't transmitted as part of the object's static state.

See [`newClassDesc` in the Object Serialization Specification, Object Serialization Stream Protocol chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#a10258).

> As for verification while deserialization, an object and the class, both will have to store the serial version reference

No they won't. I don't know what this means.

Comment: Thanks for making the reference to "class descriptor", this has indeed reduced my confusions while working over serialization.